# Why do I get "Only variables should be passed by reference" in a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting the error "Only variables should be passed by reference" if my code is like this.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `test` WHERE `username` = ? AND `active` = ?";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('si',$username,$active=1);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count);
if($stmt->fetch()){}
return ($count == 1) ? true : false;
```

However if I do it this way

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `test` WHERE `username` = ? AND `active` = ?";
$active=1
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('si',$username,$active);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count);
if($stmt->fetch()){}
return ($count == 1) ? true : false;
```

I don't get any error, even though both work correctly.
I can't understand why I get the error in the first block of code, but I don't get the error if I put $active=1; before the prepared statement, in the second block of code.

It doesn't make any sense to me.
I wonder if somebody can tell me why.

Comment: the bind parameter function wants you to 'only ' pass variables not an expression or other evaluation. This is to protect against injection which is the whole point of Binding the parameters in the first place. even though it will sometimes work

Comment: The specific issue indeed is the `$active=1`. Why do you do that? Why don't you simply pass the value `1` and all is fine?

Comment: passing 1 gives a different error, but I can't remember what that was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bind parameters function of [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is intended to

> Binds **variables** to a prepared statement as parameters

the purpose of which is to protect against sql-injection

in your first code block above you attempting to set the variable inside of the `bind_param` function and in your second block you are setting the variable before the function call

another method would be to just pass in the value

```
  $stmt->bind_param('si',$username,1);
```

though this method will work it does violate the strict interpretation, and may trigger warning and/or errors

It is best to always pass in a variable and avoid potential issues

```
$active = 1;    
$stmt->bind_param('si',$username,$active);
```

Comment: Good so I have been mostly doing it the correct way. Thankyou. I have only recently attempted to do it the first way because it seemed neater. I will of course now set the variable before the bind. I didn't notice any problem however until I accidentally turned on my errors, and then it showed up. It did actually work perfectly, but I don't like errors showing up in my code. You are right that just passing a number gives a different kind of error.